# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect** exception while trying HelloAnalyticsApiSample in Google Analytics

Tags: java, google-analytics

Getting `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect` exception while trying HelloAnalyticsApiSample in Google Analytics on the line :

```
return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
```

Do I need to provide some specific user  in the parameter "user"?

I have provided below entry in my analytics.json input file (I manually provided this entry as there was exception regarding write permissions) :

```
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "my client id ",
    "client_secret": "my client secret"
  }
}
```